# negative value of probability?

Tags: probability

Generally  probability is seen to have value between 0 and 1

I want to know is there also negative value of probability?If yes ,can that be discussed with undergrad level students or will it be too much for them to absorb?

Comment: [Scott Aaronson](https://www.scottaaronson.com/democritus/lec9.html): "Quantum mechanics is what you would inevitably come up with if you started from probability theory, and then said, let's try to generalize it so that the numbers we used to call "probabilities" can be negative numbers."